# Convert %B.%Y to date return NA in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe which have one column with date content (the data type of this columns is char): `'November.2017', 'April.2017', etc.`

I try to convert them with code below for testing:

```
strptime(c('November.2017', 'April.2017'), format='%B.%Y')
zoo::as.yearmon(c('November.2017', 'April.2017'), '%B.%Y')
as.Date(c('November.2017', 'April.2017'), format='%B.%Y')
```

Out:

```
[1] NA NA
[1] "Nov 2017" "Apr 2017"
[1] NA NA
```

As you can see, only `zoo::as.yearmon` works out, anyone could help to dig out why this happens? Thanks.

As far as I search, the issue seems raised by `time-zone`, I run `Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME', 'English')` on Rstudio, it's not working.

Updated:

```
strptime(c('November.01.2017', 'April.01.2017'), format='%B.%d.%Y')
as.Date('November.01.2017', format="%B.%d.%Y")
```

Out:

```
[1] "2017-11-01 CST" "2017-04-01 CST"
[1] "2017-11-01"
```

Comment: It might be that converting to date expects a day, which you don't have. Converting to year-month doesn't, so it works okay

Comment: Based on the link, I use `as.Date(paste('November.2017', '-01', sep=''), format = '%B.%Y-%d')`,  it returns NA as well.

Comment: For a date to be valid in standard formats, it needs to have a day associated with it. `as.yearmon` makes the assumption that day should always be the first of the month, while `as.Date` fails rather than "invent" the day. If you want to use `as.Date` you should add the day to your strings: `c('November.2017', 'April.2017') %>% gsub("\\.", "\\.01\\.", .) %>% as.Date(., "%B.%d.%Y")`

Comment: Your code with `paste` works fine for me. If it matters (dates can be OS dependent) I'm on macOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is also `parse_date`

```
library(parsedate)
parse_date((c('November.2017', 'April.2017')))
[1] "2017-11-01 UTC" "2017-04-01 UTC"
```

The output is `POSIXct` class.  It can be directly converted to `Date` class with `as.Date`

```
 as.Date(parse_date((c('November.2017', 'April.2017'))))
[1] "2017-11-01" "2017-04-01"
```

Comment: Great, it works, btw, how could remove `UTC` and keep date only?

Comment: @ahbon just wrap with `as.Date` as it is a POSIXct class from `parse_date`